# Why did Isolater.doNonTransactedWork go away in hibernate 3?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

Why did the hibernate team decide to take away the Isolater class? I was using Isolater.doNonTransactedWork in hibernate 3. Is there any way mimic the same functionality as Isolater.doNonTransactedWork in hibernate 5?